# Can there be some provable disjunction $P \vee Q$ in which neither $P$ nor $Q$ can be proved?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

More specifically, in FOL, given any theory $\Sigma$ of sentences, are there disjunctions $\varphi=P \vee Q$ such that:

1. *$\varphi$ is not provable from any single sentence of $\Sigma$* . So its not logically equivalent to an axiom.
2. $\emptyset \not \vdash \varphi $. This is implied by 1. but I want to emphasize that it's not a logical truth.
3. *$\Sigma \not \vdash P$ and $\Sigma \not \vdash Q$*. So they are not individually provable.
4. $\Sigma \not\vdash P \iff \neg Q$. So P is not provably equivalent to $\neg Q$.
5. *No axiom is of the form $(A \circ B$), where $A$ and $B$ are sentences and $\circ$ is a logical operator*. This may be a bit too strong, but I found no other way to reject trivial axioms like $(P\vee Q \vee R)$ and ($\neg R$) that give the needed $\varphi $ 'too easily'. I am open to replacing this restriction with a weaker one as long as it rules out this type of derivations. Sadly, the current one rules out ZFC, but it still allows PA and others though.

Is there such $\varphi$ in every theory? In some theory? What would be needed for it to exist? Does it exist in the interesting theories mentioned above? Could CH or other interesting unprovable sentences be part of such $\varphi$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P$ be any sentence which is independent of $T$ (or actually, any sentence which is not provable from any single sentence in $T$), and let $Q$ be any sentence which is provably equivalent to $\lnot P$, but not logically equivalent to $\lnot P$. Then $T$ proves that $P\lor Q$ is equivalent to $P\lor \lnot P$, but this is equivalence is not provable from $\emptyset$, i.e., $T\vdash P\lor Q$ but $\emptyset\not\vdash P\lor Q$.

For example, in $ZF$, let $P$ be the axiom of choice, and let $Q$ be the sentence "there exists a vector space which does not have a basis".

---

**Edit:** To deal with your new requirement that $T\not \vdash (P\leftrightarrow \lnot Q)$, just replace $P$ with $P\lor R$, where $R$ is any other statement independent from $T\cup P$. So for example, let $P$ be $AC\lor CH$, the disjunction of the axiom of choice and the continuum hypothesis, and let $Q$ be "there exists a vector space with no basis".

I'm worried this is going to quickly devolve into a "shifting the goalposts" situation. Instead of coming up with a list of increasingly complex requirements, you should take a step back and try to clearly explain the motivation behind your question. Then other users might be able to help you ask the *right* question.

Comment: Point 4 prohibits $R \implies (P \vee Q)$

Comment: @Shiranai Then maybe I don't understand what "logical operator" means...

Comment: I meant $\vee$, $\implies$, $\iff$, etc. Any of those connectives that unite two propositions.

Comment: Then $(R\rightarrow (P\lor Q))$ is not of the form $P\circ Q$.

Comment: @Shiranai Anyway, I've updated my answer with an example that's more along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: I am probably confused about the right terminology, but I count $P \vee Q$ as a proposition. And yes, the added example is indeed among the lines of what I am looking for, but not quite right. So I'll edit number 2 to rule this out too.

Comment: @Shiranai Oh! So the P and Q in your point 4 are not the same P and Q as in $\varphi$? How confusing! As I understand it then, Point 4 expresses that every axiom in the theory has to have a leading quantifier, rather than being built up with a Boolean operator at the last step? If so, this is an *extremely* unnatural condition.

Comment: ohhh yeah, that's what I meant, I'll change the variable names. I think it is too strong too, however I don't see any other way of disallowing examples as the one I gave. Also, axioms being built with a boolean operator can just be separated into individual axioms (except the 'disjunctive'-ish ones, like $\vee$ or $\implies$). Sadly, just realized ZFC is not in this class (extensionality, foundation, replacement and AC use implication), but PA is.

Comment: In any case, this condition on the form of the axioms seems to me completely irrelevant to the question. In any incomplete theory, you should expect to be able to prove disjunctions without proving either of the disjuncts. It's a completely natural and common situation.

Comment: I apologize for this constant goalpost-shifting. I guess at the core of my question was, could there be two 'interesting questions' $P$ and $Q$ that alone are unprobable but the disjunction is probable? Thinking on CH, AC, or others. My rules were trying to make $P$ and $Q$ 'interesting' in some sense but this clearly should have had more though. I will think more about this and I will be back.

Comment: @Shiranai Another way to look at it: Every implication is logically equivalent to a disjunction. So if there is any nontrivial implication between independent sentences, you'll get a provable disjunction where neither disjunct is provable. For example, over ZF, the axiom of choice (AC) implies the Banach-Tarski paradox (BT). So ZF proves the disjunction $\lnot$AC $\lor$BT, while not proving either $\lnot$AC or BT.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, should have noticed it as I was already stating that $\implies$ is disjunctive-ish.